# Given an array of integers randomly selected from 7 to 13 (included), build a function that remove the primes in the array

Tags: c, array

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

"Consider a function ​ removePrimes() be a C function that takes as input an array of integers, removes all numbers that are prime, and returns the compacted version of the array. Create an array of 200 integers, with random values between 7 and 13, and call ​ removePrimes()​ on the just filled array."

I used the following code in order to solve the task

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    
    void print_ar(int* ar, int len){
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        printf("%d ", ar[i]);
      }
      printf("\n");
      
    }
    
    int is_prime(int n ){
      if (n==1){
        return 1;
      }
      if (n == 2){
        return 1;
      }
      
      for (int i=2; i<n;i++){
        if (n % i == 0){
          return 0;
        }
      }
      
      return 1;
    }
      
    
    
    int* removePrimes(int* ar, int len, int* new_len){
      int  k = 0;
      int* temp = calloc(0, sizeof(int));
      for (int i =0;i < len; i++){
        if ( is_prime(ar[i]) == 1) {
          continue;
        }
        else{
          k=k+1;
          temp = realloc(temp, sizeof(int) * k);
          temp[k-1] = ar[i];
        }
      }
      free(ar); // is this the correct use of free()? //
      *new_len = k;
      return temp;
    
    }
      
      
      
    
    int main() {
      
      int n=0;
      while (n<200){
        printf("Insert an integer greater than 200: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
      }
      int* arr = malloc( n * sizeof(int));
      for (int i =0;i<n;i++){
        int k =rand()%7 +7;
        arr[i] = k;
      }
      int new_len = 0;
      print_ar(arr,n);
      printf("\n");
      arr = removePrimes(arr, n, &new_len);
      print_ar(arr,new_len);
    
    }
```

I am not sure about the usage of the free() function on the previous array. Is the free function used correctly, inside the removePrimes() function? Or should I call the free() outside, inside the main?

Comment: user252524: `if (n==1){ return 1; }` --> Usually 1 is not considered a _prime_.

Answer (score 1):

Given that all the values are between 7 and 13, we can implement `is_prime()` much more efficiently:

```
bool is_prime(int n)
{
    switch(n) {
        case 7: case 11: case 13: return true;
        default: return false;
    }
}
```

---

In `removePrimes()`, we allocate and reallocate memory without checking for failure.  **Always** test the return value from allocation functions is non-null before using it.

This is especially bad:

```
      temp = realloc(temp, sizeof(int) * k);
```

If `realloc()` returns a null pointer, then we have overwritten our only pointer to the memory that was allocated, so we can never free it - that's a memory leak.

According to the problem specification, I don't think we need to allocate any new memory - we could return values in the passed-in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So it would be sufficient to add an if condition that check if temp is not NULL, am I right? Secondly, if I wanted to keep the solution as it is, the free() called on 'ar' inside the removePrimes() function is working correctly?

Comment: For the `realloc()` case, we need an extra variable, so that we only overwrite `temp` if the `realloc()` was successful.  If not, we'll want to free `temp` at some point (perhaps immediately, if we're to return an error indication).

Comment: I'd say that freeing the input variable is a poor choice, as it constrains the caller to only pass allocated memory (and not automatic - "stack" - objects), and to not use that memory afterwards.  It's easier to work with code where allocations and frees can be paired up at the same level.